# Is there free credit card api or payment gateway?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, authorize.net

Actualy question says all, I need this only for testing. So, demo of some kind or 4-5 free transactions a day will do a trick.

Not looking for anything fancy.

Is there anything free?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a paypal [developer account](https://developer.paypal.com/). They have a sandbox that is identical to the real thing except it doesn't process transactions.

If you use the [back end webservice functions](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference) (not the forms based api) it should do what you want.

I dont' think it will do AVS for you though.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like very quality solution in my case. But it would be nice to find out if there is any free real solution, so I will accept your answer a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

If you sign up for an [Authorize.Net developer account](https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/) you can run an unlimited amount of test transactions for free.

Answer (score 0):

Revolution payments https://www.revolution-payments.com can provide a free solution for testing. We use them and their tokenization and vaulting feature

The fact they share in credit card processing residuals is also a plus